# Bootstrap circle not round

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, badge

I can't figure out what to do with the style, for it to display a really round circle instead of the elongated one.

Pretty new to HTML and bootstrap, don't rage at me.

[Picture of the circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Iry.png)

`<span data-mdb-toggle="tooltip" title="unread" class="badge rounded-pill bg-info" style="cursor: default">&nbsp;</span>`

Comment: You can add `badge-pill` to the class list.

Comment: Remove the &nbsp;, this creates a character which increase height to the container.

Comment: @Salketer when i do that the whole dot disappears.

Comment: @AbdullahQasemi did that, nothing changed

Comment: If you use a div instead? Or at least an inline-block? Hard to say without any reproduction...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you need to add the same width and height, so you get a completely round circle.

[see this picture for more clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdWGz.png)

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.